# Mongoose parse error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to query a collection with roughly 2000000 entries:

```
var tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
        tag: String,
        book: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }, { collection: 'tags' });

var Tag = mongoose.model('Tag', tagSchema);

Tag.count({}, function( err, count){
    console.log( "Number of tags:", count );
});

Tag.find({}, function( err, count){
   console.log(count)
   console.log(err)
}).sort({'_id': 1}).limit(10);
```

Tag.count returns the number of documents as expected, but I am getting an error when trying to access the documents with 'find'

The error is simply [Error: parseError occured]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you put all your query limit/sort/filter method calls before it executes.

```
Tag.find({}).sort({'_id': 1}).limit(10).exec(function(err, tags) {
   console.log(err, tags);
});
```

In your version since you provide a callback to `find` mongoose runs the query immediately and your calls to `limit` and `sort` are too late to take effect.